# Replace string characters from a dictionary using string.replace() returns only duplication of the string and changes nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this mini project, in which I need to replace high frequency characters in a text to 'e', 't', 'o', 'r' characters using a dictionary.

I tried doing it with `string.replace` method but it just duplicates the text instead of actually changing the characters with the dictionary values.

While debugging, I actually saw how it changes each character at a time yet 'forgetting' it the next iteration:

```py
def replace_chars_in_text(str, dict):

    dict = to_etor
    my_str = lines_reader.lower()

    for key, value in dict.items():
        new_str = my_str.replace(key, value)

    print(f"dictionary = {dict}, \nstring = {my_str}, \nfinal = {new_str}")
    return new_str
```

Comment: Are you searching for [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)?

Comment: don't use `dict` as name. Then check [ask] and post [mre], icl. sample input and expected output

Comment: Just do: `new_str = my_str = lines_reader.lower()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the line:

```
new_str = my_str.replace(key, value)
```

It keeps taking the original initialized value. If you add this above the `for` loop. It'll make it iterative and retain the value you just used.

```
new_str = my_str
```

And change the `for` loop to be iterative.

```
new_str = new_str.replace(key, value)
```

Also no need to reassign the dictionary `dict` is a non-permitted variable name (amongst others) as it doubles up with a pre-built type. Just use `to_etor`.

Or in full:

```
my_str = lines_reader.lower()
new_str = my_str

for key, value in to_etor.items():
    new_str = new_str.replace(key, value)

print(f"dictionary = {dict}, \nstring = {my_str}, \nfinal = 
{new_str}")
return new_str
```

Comment: `new_str = my_str.translate(str.maketrans(to_etor))`

Comment: @OlvinRoght add it as an answer. I was more trying to interact directly with the code, and show a change rather than here's a better way.

Comment: So that worked! (this line -  new_str = my_str.translate(str.maketrans(to_etor))) Thank you very much

Comment: @Noa customarily that means you'd accept the answer to help others.

I'd also recommend providing more information in the question so it can help others.